# How to I use output of reduce as source of another job

Tags: hadoop

I have map/reduce job, which stores it's files after reduce in a folder on HDFS.

I want to submit these results to another map/reduce job.

Do I need to use [MultiFileInputFormat](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/MultiFileInputFormat.html) or there's another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three options are mentioned in the link [Map Reduce: ChainMapper and ChainReducer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059736/map-reduce-chainmapper-and-chainreducer) on how to source the output of reducer as input of another map task.

MultiFileInputFormat is used to source multiple input formats as input to the Map tasks.